# HQL - Inner join - Joined strategy

Tags: hibernate, hql, inner-join

Fish extends LivingBeings (getters and setters generated for the same)
[image: class diagram]
 Joined strategy was used `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)`. Table structure formed [image: table structure] .
Tried inner join in sql and able to get the desired result (**test** is the database name)

```
select test.fish.colString ,test.livingbeings.name 
    from test.livingbeings
    inner join test.fish on test.fish.serialNo = test.livingbeings.serialNo;
```

With HQL createSQLQuery it is working

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "select test.fish.colString , test.livingbeings.name from test.livingbeings " +
    "inner join test.fish on livingbeings.serialNo = fish.serialNo");
```

When the same is tried using HQL createQuery getting null pointer exception?

```
Query query= session.createQuery("select l.serialNo, f.colString
   from LivingBeings l inner Join l.serialNo f");
```

Comment: You wana join a table column how is that supposed to work. I know the colum is in both tables but thats not how sql works. But you can use a join on statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have properly mapped your entities you probably want this. It's all about the mapping.

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
    "select f.serialNo, f.colString from Fish f");
```

Since Fish inherits from LivingBeings.